# Get max value from multidimensional array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I need to sort the Max Integer value containing array from the Multidimensional array to the first using Javascript / node.

```
  [{"data1":8,"data2":10,"data3":20.25,"data4":0},
{"data1":12,"data2":60,"data3":14.01,"data4":0},

{"data1":30,"data2":32.19,"data3":22.51,"data4":0}]
```

**Need Output:**

> [{"data1":12,"data2":60,"data3":14.01,"data4":0},
>   {"data1":30,"data2":32.19,"data3":22.51,"data4":0},
>   {"data1":8,"data2":10,"data3":20.25,"data4":0}]

Since 1st array has maximum value 60, second has 332.19 and third array has maximum value 20.25.

Comment: based on which integer value?

Comment: Comparing data1,data2,data3,data4 in all arrays and result which contains the maximum integer value

Comment: That being the case, the output in the question is wrong.

Comment: I have edited output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is.

```
var data= [
  {"data1":8,"data2":10,"data3":20.25,"data4":0},
  {"data1":12,"data2":60,"data3":14.01,"data4":0},
  {"data1":30,"data2":32.19,"data3":22.51,"data4":0}
];
data.sort(function(a,b){
  return Math.max(b.data1,b.data2,b.data3,b.data4)-Math.max(a.data1,a.data2,a.data3,a.data4);
});

console.log(data);
```

By the way output in the question is wrong..
it should be as follow:

```
[ { data1: 12, data2: 60, data3: 14.01, data4: 0 },
  { data1: 30, data2: 32.19, data3: 22.51, data4: 0 },
  { data1: 8, data2: 10, data3: 20.25, data4: 0 } ]
```

Comment: I have one more doubt. if consider my "data[1].data1 = 60". I need to give prefrence to the data1 value and make that array as 1st array. How to make that?

Comment: You need to learn about comparator. You can pass any comparator in sort() according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion with [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) for larger data sets without repeating call of [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
// the array to be sorted
var data = [{ "data1": 8, "data2": 10, "data3": 20.25, "data4": 0 }, { "data1": 12, "data2": 60, "data3": 14.01, "data4": 0 }, { "data1": 30, "data2": 32.19, "data3": 22.51, "data4": 0 }];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = data.map(function (el, i) {
        return {
            index: i, 
            value: Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(el).map(function (k) {
                return el[k];
            }))
        };
    });

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return data[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's very nice.